# How do I convert my postgres query to a rails object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

The following code below works as a Postgre query, i'm trying to call it inside my rails app and assigning it to an object: @agent_monthly_performance.

```
SELECT user_id AS user_id,
       to_char(created_at,'Mon-YY') AS year_month,
       sum(total_amount) AS amount,
       sum(total_lm) AS lm
FROM   agent_sales
WHERE  created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 year'
GROUP BY user_id, year_month"
```

Once that works, will I be able to call it via @agent_monthly_performance.year_month? I'm aware that i've created new columns that aren't in my schema via "AS" command. (ex. year_month).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` to execute row sql queries in rails

```
@agent_monthly_performance = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT user_id AS user_id, to_char(created_at,'Mon-YY') AS year_month, sum(total_amount) AS amount, sum(total_lm) AS lm FROM   agent_sales WHERE  created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 year' GROUP BY user_id, year_month").to_a
```

Comment: Your answer outputs this:  => #<PG::Result:0x007fb3755e0030 status=PGRES_TUPLES_OK ntuples=3 nfields=4 cmd_tuples=3>  Not really sure how to access that.

Comment: you just need to add `.to_a` at the end. I update the answer.

Answer (score 3):

`MyModel.find_by_sql(query)` will still inherit model instance. You might need to check it further

Comment: This works but only for user_id, the attribute available in my table. Is there a way to output my three other SELECT requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
sql = <<-SQL
  SELECT user_id AS user_id,
       to_char(created_at,'Mon-YY') AS year_month,
       sum(total_amount) AS amount,
       sum(total_lm) AS lm
  FROM   agent_sales
  WHERE  created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 year'
  GROUP BY user_id, year_month
SQL

SomeModel.find_by_sql(sql)
```

Comment: I tried doing this to my model: AgentSale. It doesn't produce an error but the output is:      [#<AgentSale id: nil, user_id: 14>, #<AgentSale id: nil, user_id: 13>, #<AgentSale id: nil, user_id: 1>]   It seems to only select the attributes that is in the model. What about the 3 other entries in my SELECT that has some computations to it, how can I get that to output?

Comment: Looks like you need to add another table to your `FROM` statement. Currently you're only pulling from `agent_sales`, which I'm guessing is only a join table.

Comment: All my data is in agent_sales, do you mean I need to add another agent_sales table and join them together?

Comment: Not necessarily. I didn't see that you were adding 'columns' with an AS statement.